# How do I play Goat MMO Simulator with a party?

Tags: goat-simulator

I want to play Goat MMO Simulator with other people and party up. When I try and talk to people in-game no-one answers me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Goat MMO Simulator is a MMO Simulator, not an actual game. If it was an actual MMO it would be called Goat Simulator MMO.

Goat Simulator will not be multiplayer due to the restrictions of the physics sandbox the game uses.

Comment: It's like my theoretical degree in physics.

Comment: You can play goat simulator as a local coop with another player tho.

Comment: I nominate this game to become an actual MMO. I don't care how impossible it is, I want this to be a real MMO.